# PyQT5 program returning error only during first compile run

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pyqt5, spyder

The following example, when run in a new ipython console (spyder) returns "-1", but only at the first try. After that it seems to work fine.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

from GUI import Ui_MainWindow  # importing our generated file

import sys
import numpy as np

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(mywindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

application = mywindow()

application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The error is as follows:

> >runfile('C:/Users/xxx.py', wdir='C:/Users/xx/Documents/3dPackaging')
>   An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
>
> SystemExit: -1
>
> C:\Users\xx\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2969: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
>     warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
>
> %tb
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/xxx.py', wdir='C:/Users/xx')
>
> File "C:\Users\xx\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users\xx\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/xx/Documents/3dPackaging/VersandkartonsPacken.py", line 64, in 
>       sys.exit(app.exec())
>
> SystemExit: -1

I have no idea what this could be, but as this is supposed to be a standalone program one day, I'm afraid it might be messy then, so i'd rather fix it. Anything I should try?

It's not reproducible without the GUI.py, so here it is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1127, 910)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_schliessen = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_schliessen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(930, 770, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_schliessen.setObjectName("pushButton_schliessen")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 20, 421, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 770, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tableWidget_input = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 80, 421, 671))
        self.tableWidget_input.setObjectName("tableWidget_input")
        self.tableWidget_input.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget_input.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget_output = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget_output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 80, 441, 671))
        self.tableWidget_output.setObjectName("tableWidget_output")
        self.tableWidget_output.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget_output.setRowCount(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1127, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_schliessen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Schliessen"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Versandkartons Packen"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Berechnen"))
```

It seems to be related to [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-PyQt-applications-within-Spyder), app is never none but already returns a QCoreApplication in the first run. However , moving it into a function doesn't work. And I can't reproduce in the console the behaviour that actually makes it work in the second run. Something seems to change the QCorEApplication into a working one.

In two now deleted answers (didn't work), it was suggested to use `if __name__ == '__main__':` and move the application call into a new class. That hasn't worked.

Comment: With Python 3.7 and qt5 version 5.11.3 I do not get this error. The window seems to load correctly.

Comment: ...neither on 3.6.6

Comment: I can't duplicate this problem with Python 3.7/Qt5 5.9.6. Can you tell us some more detail about your environment please so we can try and reproduce this? Thanks!

Comment: @RobBricheno yes yes, sorry, I don't have access right now, didn't expect it to be a version thing. I installed the latest 64bit anaconda with spyder just a week ago. Python 3.7. Not sure if that's enough to duplicate it though. PyQt5

Comment: @DonQuiKong I just did the same thing for my test (fresh install, on a Windows 10 platform). What OS were you using?

Comment: @RobBricheno uhm, win 10 I think. That's ... unexpected. I thought it would be a general thing about the qt application.

Comment: I have just tried this on a different system with a different version and was not able to reproduce the error. Thank you all for your help. If someone wants to add an answer that it's apparently either a very narrow version thing or a local system thing, no need to let that bounty expire. @RobBricheno

Comment: @roeen30 one should be able to ping multiple persons

Comment: @PavelM. I mean seriously ;)

Comment: @DonQuiKong thanks for the update, and thanks, will do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must be related to a peculiarity of the local system. We (commenters on the original question) have not been able to reproduce the error when installing the requirements from scratch in a clean environment (even when the environment very closely matches the affected system).

Please try reinstalling your environment, or running this on a different system, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21478034)

Comment: @HenryWoody how does this not answer the question? The problem is reproducible only on my specific system, I couldn't even reproduce it elsewhere myself. The next person coming here with that error needs to know that their system or specific combination of versions is at fault.

Comment: This post does not provide specific steps to solve the problem, it just states where the issue is coming from generally. Maybe someone will find the information useful, but that does not make it an answer.

Comment: @HenryWoody but it does. Change version or system. Problem solved.

Comment: @HenryWoody Normally I would agree with your first comment, but OP explicitly asked for a post like this in the comments. I've edited it a little to rephrase it to look more like a traditional answer. It isn't really satisfactory, and I'd love it if someone came along with a better answer!

Comment: @HenryWoody yes because now I know that I can easily “not have“ that problem ;). Sure, it doesn't explain why the problem exists, but it's *good enough*.

Answer (score 0):

I use conda which might be related to the issue. I just upgraded PyQT5 with `pip install PyQt5`, making this issue disappear. So that seems to be the easiest solution.